# Flutter: How to send response in raw body data?

Tags: api, flutter, xmlhttprequest, response, flutter-test

[This is ScreenShot of Response of raw body data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFeSH.png)

Body raw data:

```
{"getOpenQuiz":[{"Id":1,"openquizInstruction":"Copy the following word","openquizWord":"Important","possible_answers":["Important","Importnat","import"],"quizstatus":1,"userAnswer":"important"},{"Id":2,"openquizInstruction":"test","openquizWord":"test","possible_answers":["test","testty","adsf","dfgdfg"],"quizstatus":0,"userAnswer":"tttt"},{"Id":3,"openquizInstruction":"dfgdfg","openquizWord":"dsfgsd","possible_answers":["fgsdf","gsdfg","dfgrertert","sdfgsdfg"],"quizstatus":0,"userAnswer":"dsfgsd"},{"Id":4,"openquizInstruction":"Copy the following word","openquizWord":"Important","possible_answers":["Important","Importat","Importnt"],"quizstatus":0,"userAnswer":"importnat"},{"Id":5,"openquizInstruction":"Copy the word","openquizWord":"color","possible_answers":["colour","color"],"quizstatus":0,"userAnswer":"coluor"}]}
```

Comment: do you want to `get` that json or do you want to `post` something like that json.

Comment: @aligator I want to post that json raw data to get the response from the API

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [HTTP plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/http) and the REST is easy.

example for how to do it:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FlatButton(
            child: Text('post'),
            onPressed: (){
              post('https://www.example.com/api',
                body: jsonEncode({ // body of post
                  'title' : 'test title'
                })
              ).then((response){
                if(response.statusCode==200){
                  String body = response.body; // body of response
                  Map<String,dynamic> decodedJson = jsonDecode(body);
                  print(decodedJson);
                }
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is not working, I want to pass response in body raw then i get response which have to show in result page.